# Debugging a problem with shadows in React three fiber, and why my shadows are "cut"

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm new to React three fiber and JS. I was following a tutorial on ytb to set up a simple scene, 3 box that rotate, lights and shadows but I don't know why my shadows are not rendering properly. What is happening?

That is my code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { SoftShadows, MeshWobbleMaterial, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei';
import { useSpring, a } from '@react-spring/three';


const SpinningMesh = ({position, color,args, speed}) => {
  const mesh = useRef(null);
  useFrame(() => (mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y +=0.01));
  
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  const props = useSpring({
    scale: expand ? [1.4, 1.4, 1.4]:[1,1,1],
  });

  const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(false);
  const propsa = useSpring({
    rotation: rotate ? [2, 2, 1]:[1,1,1],
  });

  return(
    <a.mesh 
      onClick={()=> {setExpand(!expand); setRotate(!rotate)}
      } 
      scale={props.scale}
      castShadow 
      position={position} 
      rotation={propsa.rotation}
      ref={mesh}>
      <boxBufferGeometry attach='geometry' args={args} />
      <MeshWobbleMaterial attach='material' color={color} speed={speed} factor={0.6}/>
    </a.mesh>
  )
}

function App() {
  
  return (
   <>
    <Canvas shadows attach='shadow-camera' camera={{position: [-5, 2, 10], fov: 60}}>
    <SoftShadows />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.3} />
      <directionalLight 
        castShadow
        position={[0, 20, 0]}
        intensity={1.7}

        shadow-mapSize-width={2048}
        shadow-mapSize-height={2048}
        shadowCameraFar={50}
        shadowCameraLeft={-10}
        shadowCameraRight={10}
        shadowCameraTop={10}
        shadowCameraBottom={-10}
      />
      <pointLight position={[-10, 0, -20]} intensity={0.5} />
      <pointLight position={[0, -10, 0]} intensity={1.5}  />
      <group>
        <mesh receiveShadow rotation={[-Math.PI /2 , 0, 0]} position={[0, -2 ,0]} >
          <planeBufferGeometry attach='geometry'  args={[20,20]} />
          <shadowMaterial attach='material' opacity={1.3} />
          
        </mesh>
        <SpinningMesh position={[0, 1, 0]} color={'blue'} args={[3,2,1]} speed={2}/>
        <SpinningMesh position={[-3, 1, -5]} color={'pink'} speed={6} />
        <SpinningMesh position={[5, 1, -2]} color={'pink'} speed={6}/>
      </group>

      <OrbitControls/>
    </Canvas>
   </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I searched everywhere but I didn't find any fix. What can I try next?

Comment: Could you upload an image of what you are seeing that is incorrect? Please use the image upload device in the question editor.